# Rewrite a future tense sentences with (needs)?

Tags: future-tense

I have just finished an English exam and there was an rewrite question like this:

> 1-His car broke down.He is going to repair it next week.      (needs)

It needs to be rewritten using the word *needs* and I am not sure what the right answer is. Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: You can't 'rewrite the sentence' using the verb _need_ (in any of its forms, eg needs or needing) in place of _be going to_. They have different meanings. But since your 'I have just finished an english exam and there was an rewrite question' contains two obvious mistakes as well as an unusual usage, one wonders what the original wording was.

Comment: !!Assumptions!!

Answer (score 2):

**His car broke down. He *needs* to repair it next week.**

or

**His car broke down, and he *needs* to repair it next week.**

First, the instructions did not ***require*** that the second sentence remain in the future tense. Second, the present form of the verb *needs* enjoys the future connotation of *next week*. Third, the instructions do not **prohibit** combining the two sentences. There are many other ways to rewrite the sentences, provided the instruction did not add specific restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the sentence is correct as it is and needs no modification.  The phrase "going to" states an intention to do something in the future.

However, if you *must* re-write it using the word "need" in a future tense, then the future tense of "need" is "will need".

His car broke down.  He will need to repair it next week.

Comment: I think of that too,but the problem is there is S after need so it is needs

Comment: As "needs" is the given word, it would have to be "He needs to repair it (by) next week."